# Feature Tracking by using Lucas Kanade algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, tracking, feature-detection

[Lucas Kanade Feature Tracker Refer Page 6](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b04/algo_tracking.pdf)                                          I am implementing the Lucas Kanade Feature Tracker in C++.

One thing is unclear in implementing the equation 23 which is mentioned in attached paper. I think Matrix G calculation should happened inside K loop, not outside K loop. In case when Patch B is present at the border in frame j, That time it is not useful to use full G Spatial Gradient Matrix which is calculated before K loop (as mentioned in paper). For Frame j, Matrix G should calculate for the showed patch B portion only.

```
                            Patch A                    Patch B
                              |                           |
                              |                           |
                         -----|---                       -|-------
                        |   |---| |                     | |       |
                        |   |   | |                     |--|      |
                        |   |---| |                     |  |      |
                        |         |                     |--|      |
                         ---------                       ---------
                         Frame i                          Frame j
```

Comment: Why should `G` be inside the second loop? There's no point in recomputing gradient for the same image till convergence.

Comment: @a-Jays I think you are telling correct .I will work on this .

Comment: @a-Jays,do you  know any link from where I can download the paper for Luacs Kanade optimization also .So I can think while development only !!

Comment: It's not something a quick Google search wouldn't be able to give you.. And I can't figure out _which_ of the many many such papers you mean.

Comment: @a-Jays,MY question is in related to a feature which is close to the boundary .